# UITableView showing extra separator lines, on top of cells, when reloading page

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I have a UITableView that contains mutiple sections. When my tab page first loads, everything looks fine. But when I navigate to a different tab, and come back, my UITableView has some extra separator lines.

I verified that numberOfRowsInSection is properly returning 2.

My row height is set to AutomaticDimension.

I am calling reloadData in viewDidAppear.

[image: UITableView with extra lines]

I tried setting the background color of my table cells to white, but the extra lines are still visible.

The UITableView is inside of a UIScrollView, which I know is frowned upon, but I am doing the calculation to calculate the size of the TableView. Everything works perfectly on initial load, it's not until I return to the tab that I get the extra lines.

Comment: Checking your view debugger should give you hints to as to what the problem is.

Comment: This is the first I have heard of a View Debugger. I am writing this app in Xamarin, so I don;t have access to all of XCode's tools.

Comment: Could you post the code in ACCOUNT view controller ?

Comment: Is this all designed in Storyboard / IB? Or are you adding views via code?

Comment: I am not using Storyboard, all of my views are created in code.

@ColeX-MSFT, give me a bit, and I'll upload my post with some code.

Comment: @Dave - this doesn't really look like "extra lines" ... it looks like your code is maybe adding multiple table views, overlaid on top of each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my AccountViewController, I was calling an API to get the user's get account information in ViewDidAppear.

Instead of creating a new TableViewSource, I would clear out the existing data, and the repopulate it with the result of the API call. The flow was something like this.

- Clear the Source Data
- Call the API
- Populate Source with API data
- Reload Table Data

I ended up solving the problem by making a call to Reload Table Data after the source was cleared.

- Clear the Source Data
- Reload Table Data
- Call the API
- Populate Source with API data
- Reload Table Data

Perhaps not the most efficient approach, but it was the easiest to implement within the current structure of the page.